# Symony 4 - Migrating from 3.x to 4.x Error with server:run

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have been working on migrating my Symfony 3.x project to the latest Symfony 4.x version. What I did was create a fresh install of Symfony 4.x and have been moving my bundle to Symfony 4 as a the main App namespace (renamed all my namespaces and use). I followed the correct folder structure in the Symfony 4 docs, but I obviously missed something.

When I try to do "bin/console server:run", I am presented with this error:

```
    php bin/console server:run

    Fatal error: Uncaught 
    Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load 
    class "Kernel" from namespace "App".
    Did you forget a "use" statement for "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel"? 
    in C:\wamp\www\DBViewer\bin\console:37
    Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in C:\wamp\www\DBViewer\bin\console on line 37
```

I checked line 37 in the console and all it was:

```
$kernel = new Kernel($env, $debug);
```

I've compared the the bin/console from my working Symfony 4 app to this Symfony 4 app, and it is the same. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Did you also adjust your app/AppKernel.php as well as bin/console?

Answer (score 1):

Verfify your composer.json file. In Symfony 3.4 it used to be:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

while in Symfony 4 it is simply:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

In Symfony 4 your AppKernel.php must be directly in "src/" folder and not in "app/".

Hope this helps.

Comment: This ^ though a fresh installation of Symfony 3.4 is also bundleless. (3.4 and 4.0 are nearly identical, 4.0 just has 3.x deprecations removed.) Symfony 3.3 was the latest version that used app bundles as standard.